# Ubuntu Core 22 - seeding network config in custom image

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-core, custom-installer

Can anyone point me in the right direction for seeding a network config into a custom image?  Documentation seems rather limited on this topic with Ubuntu Core.  I found the [system.network.netplan](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/ubuntu-core-configuration#heading--netplan) configuration options which I think can be added as a [system: value in gadget.yaml](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/gadget-snaps) when building a custom Gadget.  But I can't figure out the correct syntax for adding WiFi SSID's and PSK's using the `snap set system` command.  Should the `<key>:<value>`'s in the YAML mirror those from snap get/set system commands?

Or if there is an easier method, such as a netplan.yaml, I'd love to hear it.  I'm really just looking to bypass the human interaction required on first boot and auto-connect to a list of predefined wireless networks.  I've already built a custom image, have an auto-import.assert for a system user account, and defined `service.console-conf.disable:true` to disable the initial configuration dialog, but I'm still missing the networking part of the puzzle.  Any suggestions or an example would be greatly appreciated.

Mods: Please feel free to retag this post if there is a better place on the forum for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The correct syntax in gadget.yaml is

```
defaults:
  system:
    system:
      network:
        netplan:
          network:
            wifis:
              wlan0:
                access-points:
                  WiFiNetworkName01:
                    auth:
                      key-management: "psk"
                      password: "WiFiPassword"
                  WiFiNetworkName02:
                    auth:
                      key-management: "psk"
                      password: "WiFiPassword"
                dhcp4: true
```